# cout is not displaying char array (char buf) on console or output buffer in OpenCL HelloWorld problem

Tags: c++, opencl

[image]This is the `HelloWorld.cl` kernel file. When I debug I can see the `buf` has `helloworld\n` but it doesn't display on the console.

```
__kernel void HelloWorld(__global char* data)
{
    data[0] = 'H';
    data[1] = 'e';
    data[2] = 'l';
    data[3] = 'l';
    data[4] = 'o';
    data[5] = ' ';
    data[6] = 'w';
    data[7] = 'o';
    data[8] = 'r';
    data[9] = 'l';
    data[10] = 'd';
    data[11] = '!';
    data[12] = '\n';
}
```

I am trying OpenCL for the first time. I am able to compile the code the but output is not displaying on the console.

`CreateProgram` sets up intial context and program.

```
cl::Program CreateProgram(const std::string& file)
{
    std::vector<cl::Platform> platforms;
    cl::Platform::get(&platforms);
    auto platform = platforms.front();
    std::vector<cl::Device> devices;
    platform.getDevices(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU, &devices);
    auto device = devices.front();
    std::ifstream helloWorldFile(file);
    std::string src(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(helloWorldFile), 
        (std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()));
    cl::Program::Sources sources(1, std::make_pair(src.c_str(), 
        src.length() + 1));
    cl::Context context(device);
    cl::Program program(context, sources);
    auto err = program.build("-cl-std=CL1.2");
    return program;
}
int main()
{
    auto program = CreateProgram("HelloWorld.cl");
    auto context = program.getInfo<CL_PROGRAM_CONTEXT>();
    auto devices = context.getInfo<CL_CONTEXT_DEVICES>();
    auto device = devices.front();
    char buf[16];// output buffer where helloWorld is stored
    cl::Buffer memBuf = cl::Buffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY | 
        CL_MEM_HOST_READ_ONLY, sizeof(buf));
    cl::Kernel kernel(program, "HelloWorld");
    kernel.setArg(0, memBuf);
    cl::CommandQueue queue(context, device);
    queue.enqueueTask(kernel);
    queue.enqueueReadBuffer(memBuf, CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(buf), buf);
    std::cout << buf << std::endl; //I want buf to display on console but it is always blank
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check for error codes returned by OpenCL functions - the information why is not working is very likely there. If it's still not working then show us implementation of `HelloWorld.cl` and `CreateProgram`.

Comment: I have added createProgram. There is no errors. I have used #define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS.

Comment: Still no `HelloWorld.cl`. Include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I've built this myself and it's working fine for me: it produces the expected output. I made some changes in the code because I had compile errors - it's probably from the fact I use latest `cl2.hpp`. That's just to show how sometimes important are the small details. To increase the chance to help you with this problem you really need to include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thanks, I cannot use openCL 2.0 as my card only supports 1.2.

Comment: Using `cl2.hpp` does not necessarily imply `OpenCL 2.0`. The `OpenCL 1.2` compatibility can be enforced using some defines. See my answer.

Comment: I used #define __CL_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS to find error and I am getting clCreateKernel : -46. I know this is INVALID FILE NAME.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a nul-terminating character while initialising the string in your kernel.

I'm not sure this error should be completely preventing any output at all though; is your program perhaps crashing instead of printing output?

Anyway, to fix this specific bug (there may be others), add

```
data[13] = '\0';
```

to your kernel.

Comment: I have added picture of my debug window. I can see the value in buf but is not able to display on the console. If is use &buf I can display the address but not the values

Comment: @redPanda I just noticed your `cin.get()`. Have you tried putting `std::cout << std::flush;` before this?

Answer (score 0):

With below settings using `cl2.hpp` enforcing `OpenCL 1.2` compatibility it's working for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#define CL_HPP_MINIMUM_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#define CL_HPP_TARGET_OPENCL_VERSION 120
#define CL_HPP_ENABLE_EXCEPTIONS
#define CL_USE_DEPRECATED_OPENCL_1_2_APIS

#include "cl2.hpp"
```

And one more change in the code. Below didn't compile:

```
cl::Program::Sources sources(1, std::make_pair(src.c_str(), 
    src.length() + 1));
```

and I changed it to:

```
cl::Program::Sources sources;
sources.push_back(src);
```